# Class field as function argument

Tags: java

I have a class with some fields:

```
public class ClassA {
private MyType myField;
...

public ClassA() { MyType myField = new MyType(14);}

public MyType get () {
return myField;
}

public void set(double value){
myField.set(value);
}
}
```

And this is MyType class:

```
public class MyType {
private double zzz;

public MyType (double zzz) {this.zzz=zzz;}

public void set (double zzz) {this.zzz=zzz;}

public double get () {return zzz}
}
```

Then I have another class:

```
public ClassB {

public ClassB(MyType ccc) {
myFunc(ccc);
}

private void myFunc (MyType ccc) {
ccc.set(ccc.get()+9);
}
```

In a function in another class I have this:

```
...
public void anotherFunc(ClassA myObject){
ClassB ddd = new ClassB(myObject.get());
}
...
```

Now, if I call anotherFunc then the value of myObject.myField.zzz becomes 23 (14+9). I want myObject.myField.zzz to be 14, and not to be modiefied if I pass it as a function argument.

And, most important, I don't understand why this happens, since I pass it in a function, but in that function I don't use that object itself.

Comment: Long story short: this happens because you are passing around a mutable class, instead of changing it to an immutable class, or making deep copy.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca sorry I modified ClassB in my example. Now it should be correct

Comment: @dasblinkenlight so how can I avoid it to change? I resolved by creating a double variable and passing it as an argument, but it isn't very "elegant", I mean, I think there is a more "standard" way

Comment: Remove the setter, and replace calls to it with re-assignments of the entire objects. Read about immutable objects to learn more.

Comment: How are you checking the value for myObject.bbb.zzz?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ok thanks I'll search online

Comment: @Thatalent Log.d

Comment: I meant are you doing something like Log.d(myObject.get().get())

Comment: @Thatalent that's not exactly my class of course that's just an example, but I think so

Comment: Okay. I'm asking because your logic does not seem wrong. I took part of the code posted here and ran it locally to test (without changing what it is actually doing). If the variable zzz is a double type then it is immutable by nature and only calling `MyType.set(someDouble)` would change it. In other words, if the above code is running then whatever is causing your problem is apart of something else. You can still remove the setter method to eliminate any chance of the value changing but that would cover up whatever is actually causing the issue.

Comment: @Thatalent thanks for the attention, by the way I noticed that the "logic" of my code is different from the example I posted. Now I modified it and it is more similiar to my real code. By the way if I create a new object of the same type of ccc in myFunc and I copy the values of ccc then it works. My problem is that I really don't understand why if I pass in an object as an argument and then I make operations on the argument, then the values of the object passed in change. I don't understand the logic, even because I met this problem after 2 months I use Java, I've never noticed before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: `ccc.set(ccc.get()+9)` is the same as `ccc.zzz = ccc.zzz + 9` because ccc.set() sets whatever you pass into it onto ccc.zzz and ccc is the object myObject.bbb.

Okay with you're updated code I see the issue. In your `class ClassB` you are setting your calling set on cc which is not needed.

```
private void myFunc (MyType ccc) {
  ccc.set(ccc.get()+9); //this line makes your object ccc change values after adding 9 You should not be doing this if you want ccc to not change.
}
```

The previous version of your code was better and properly set the sum of cc.zzz and 9 to a new object of type MyType. This seems to have been just a mistake and it happens to the best of us.

Comment: Thank you, now I understood what happened. I still have a bit of confusion on my mind but I think I'm on the right way to understand.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you were able to figure things out and fix the problem. Don't be afraid to ask more questions and look up whatever you need to help.